# How to change $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH

Tags: ros, path, roscreate-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, there.. I'm new using ROS and I'm doing the tutorial for creating a package (http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage).
I tried to  do "roscreate-pkg" and I got this

```
 jesus@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace$ roscreate-pkg prueba1
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
WARNING: current working directory is not on ROS_PACKAGE_PATH!
Please update your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH environment variable.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Created package directory /home/jesus/ros_workspace/prueba1
Created package file /home/jesus/ros_workspace/prueba1/Makefile
Created package file /home/jesus/ros_workspace/prueba1/manifest.xml
Created package file /home/jesus/ros_workspace/prueba1/CMakeLists.txt
Created package file /home/jesus/ros_workspace/prueba1/mainpage.dox

Please edit prueba1/manifest.xml and mainpage.dox to finish creating your package
jesus@ubuntu:~/ros_workspace$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
/opt/ros/electric/stacks
```

So I realized that my path is placed in root and I want to move it to "/home/jesus/ros_workspace"
How can I do this?                Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30586/how-to-change-$ros_package_path/) by [xHenrYx14](https://answers.ros.org/users/2065/xhenryx14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-03-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add this line to your ~/.bashrc directly under the call to /opt/ros/distro/setup.bash:

```
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=~/ros_workspace:${ROS_PACKAGE_PATH}
```

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The best way to change ROS_PACKAGE_PATH is to create an overlay. See [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/10431/help-with-installing-packages-and-repositories#15377) answer (still for diamondback). For electric, just replace all occurrences of diamondback with electric. Also, you can skip the roslocate step at the end since you don't want to install bosch_drivers.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2012-03-27**:
Thanks Lorenz ..